# How to calculate the differences between a set of different matrices and a matrix

Tags: r, for-loop, matrix

I already got the following codes

```
P <- matrix(c(0.8,0.2,0.5,0.5),2,2,byrow=TRUE)
ev <- eigen(P)
rvec <- ev$vectors
lvec <- ginv(rvec)
pi_eig <-lvec[1,]/sum(lvec[1,])
powers <- 0:20
upowers <- lapply(powers, function(k) P %^% k)
A <- for (i in 1:20) {upowers[i]-pi_eig}
```

I want to calculate different A from different powers of P minus the stationary distribution of P, as what showed in the picture.

[image]

The last code is wrong , and I could not figure out how to solve this problem.

Comment: Are you trying to compute `A` or `A^k`? The former being much more complex.

Comment: A^1=P^1-p^infinity, A^2=P^2-P^infinity,....,A^k=P^k-P^infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution to compute `A^k`:

Supposing you already have your matrices `P` and `P_infty` which I will refer to as `Q`. You can then the do the following

```
# Data
set.seed(123)
P <- matrix(runif(9), 3L, 3L)
Q <- matrix(runif(9), 3L, 3L)
# Computes P^k (matrix multiplication, not R's P^k!)
matMultK <- function (k) {
  txt <- paste("P", paste(rep("%*% P", k), collapse = " "))
  eval(expr = parse(text = txt))
}
# Compute the results
lapply(1:3, function (k) matMultK(k) - Q)
```

The function `matMultK` will compute the matrix power `P^k` of `P` *not* R's version (in R `P^k` is done element-wise). Note that with some minor modifications, you can have also `P` to be and an argument.

Finally, using `lapply` is a convenient way of calculating the sequence `A^k`. Here again, there are many alternatives.